# Escaping special characters in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, symbols, characters

I need to produce a scatter plot involving many special characters, including LaTeX special characters like `$`, `\` and `%`. For that I use tikz. I first produce the plot in Python with matplotlib, which looks like this:

[image]

Then I use [tikzplotlib](https://github.com/nschloe/tikzplotlib) to produce a .tex file. The output for a plot of `a`, `b`, `c`, `*` and `%` looks like this:

```
% This file was created by tikzplotlib v0.8.2.
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.172549019607843,0.372549019607843,0.537254901960784}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.925490196078431,0,0.549019607843137}

\begin{axis}[
hide x axis,
hide y axis,
tick pos=left,
xmin=-3.11107425768857, xmax=4.04556696239392,
ymin=-1.96452826220114, ymax=3.30474420528924
]
\addplot [only marks, draw=color0, fill=color0, colormap/viridis]
table{%
x                      y
-1.05731886163643 -1.72501587731521
-2.78577238404846 -0.843765364632213
3.72026508875381 -1.22034965712686
0.00465397081060324 0.723899078670965
0.118172186120475 3.06523182040332
};
\draw[] (axis cs:-1.05731886163643,-1.72501587731521) -- (axis cs:-1.05731886163643,-1.72501587731521);
\node at (axis cs:-1.05731886163643,-1.72501587731521)[
  scale=0.5,
  text=color1,
  rotate=0.0
]{a};
\draw[] (axis cs:-2.78577238404846,-0.843765364632213) -- (axis cs:-2.78577238404846,-0.843765364632213);
\node at (axis cs:-2.78577238404846,-0.843765364632213)[
  scale=0.5,
  text=color1,
  rotate=0.0
]{b};
\draw[] (axis cs:3.72026508875381,-1.22034965712686) -- (axis cs:3.72026508875381,-1.22034965712686);
\node at (axis cs:3.72026508875381,-1.22034965712686)[
  scale=0.5,
  text=color1,
  rotate=0.0
]{c};
\draw[] (axis cs:0.00465397081060324,0.723899078670965) -- (axis cs:0.00465397081060324,0.723899078670965);
\node at (axis cs:0.00465397081060324,0.723899078670965)[
  scale=0.5,
  text=color2,
  rotate=0.0
]{*};
\draw[] (axis cs:0.118172186120475,3.06523182040332) -- (axis cs:0.118172186120475,3.06523182040332);
\node at (axis cs:0.118172186120475,3.06523182040332)[
  scale=0.5,
  text=color2,
  rotate=0.0
]{%};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I already tried escaping special character with `\verb||`. I did this by surrounding the characters righ tin the source by having the scatter plot annotated with `\verb|<some char>|` rather than `<some char>`:

[image]

Resulting in (only difference is the node content):

```
% This file was created by tikzplotlib v0.8.2.
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.925490196078431,0,0.549019607843137}

\begin{axis}[
hide x axis,
hide y axis,
tick pos=left,
xmin=-2.21660561653058, xmax=3.61518365126537,
ymin=-2.10679459204322, ymax=3.24590880736972
]
\addplot [only marks, draw=color0, fill=color0, colormap/viridis]
table{%
x                      y
-1.90642120048988 0.361422280176018
3.35010232091101 -1.86348989206991
-1.95152428617622 -0.405029504344616
1.63436899897306 3.0026041073964
-1.12652583321798 -1.0955069911579
};
\draw[] (axis cs:-1.90642120048988,0.361422280176018) -- (axis cs:-1.90642120048988,0.361422280176018);
\node at (axis cs:-1.90642120048988,0.361422280176018)[
  scale=0.5,
  text=color1,
  rotate=0.0
]{\verb|a|};
\draw[] (axis cs:3.35010232091101,-1.86348989206991) -- (axis cs:3.35010232091101,-1.86348989206991);
\node at (axis cs:3.35010232091101,-1.86348989206991)[
  scale=0.5,
  text=color1,
  rotate=0.0
]{\verb|b|};
\draw[] (axis cs:-1.95152428617622,-0.405029504344616) -- (axis cs:-1.95152428617622,-0.405029504344616);
\node at (axis cs:-1.95152428617622,-0.405029504344616)[
  scale=0.5,
  text=color1,
  rotate=0.0
]{\verb|c|};
\draw[] (axis cs:1.63436899897306,3.0026041073964) -- (axis cs:1.63436899897306,3.0026041073964);
\node at (axis cs:1.63436899897306,3.0026041073964)[
  scale=0.5,
  text=color1,
  rotate=0.0
]{\verb|*|};
\draw[] (axis cs:-1.12652583321798,-1.0955069911579) -- (axis cs:-1.12652583321798,-1.0955069911579);
\node at (axis cs:-1.12652583321798,-1.0955069911579)[
  scale=0.5,
  text=color1,
  rotate=0.0
]{\verb|%|};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

This does not help however.

Is there a straightforward way to produce valid escaped LaTeX strings in the source before producing the tikz-code? I want to avoid manually fixing the generated code afterwards. But if there is no other way, then that would also do.

Comment: In your Python code, could you replace ```\``` with `\textbackslash`, `%` with `\%` etc.?

Comment: Anyways, the code produced by `tikzplotlib` doesn't work that well, but the `pgfplots` code you need for this is quite simple, so I think I'd suggest writing x, y and character to a text file, and using `pgfplots` code like in this example: https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/be982dca05f1aa0efd27185f6218aea8

Comment: `\string` works in most cases, except `%`, `}`, `\ `, and for `#` you would need `##`.